# How to access matomo via a subpage on nginx Ubuntu

Tags: nginx, webserver, ubuntu-18.04, matomo

I am using an Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS webserver that is configured with nginx. The server is running and I can access any file on my mainpage example.com. Now I want to install matomo on the server. However, I can only manage to access the installation via my root url [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). Whenever I try to move the Matomo-access to a subpage e.g. example.com/matomo/ my sever sends a 404 instead. I think I have made a mistake in creating a configuration setup for calling subpages, but I cannot figure out what went wrong. I am new to nginx and have spent the last 2 days testing for a solution. Any help would be highly appreciated. Please find my server.conf, as well as the matomo.conf below.

My server config-file is as follows:

```
server {
    listen                  443 ssl http2;
    listen                  [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name             www.example.com;
    set                     $base /var/www/example.com;
    root                    $base/public;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

    # security
    include                 nginxconfig.io/security.conf;

    # logging
    access_log              /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log warn;

    # index.php
    index                   index.php;

    # index.php fallback
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # handle .php
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        include      nginxconfig.io/php_fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

My matomo.conf:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.example.com/subpage example.com/subpage; 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/matomo.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/matomo.error.log;


    ## SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;

    add_header Referrer-Policy origin always; 
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;

    root /var/www/example.com/subpage/matomo/; # path to matomo instance

    index index.php;

    ## only allow accessing the following php files
    location ~ ^/(index|matomo|piwik|js/index|plugins/HeatmapSessionRecording/configs)\.php {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY ""; 
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock; 
    }

    ## deny access to all other .php files
    location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    ## serve all other files normally
    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    ## disable all access to the following directories
    location ~ ^/(config|tmp|core|lang) {
        deny all;
        return 403; # replace with 404 to not show these directories exist
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ js/container_.*_preview\.js$ {
        expires off;
        add_header Cache-Control 'private, no-cache, no-store';
    }

    location ~ \.(gif|ico|jpg|png|svg|js|css|htm|html|mp3|mp4|wav|ogg|avi|ttf|eot|woff|woff2|json)$ {
        allow all;
        ## Cache images,CSS,JS and webfonts for an hour
        ## Increasing the duration may improve the load-time, but may cause old files to show after an Matomo upgrade
        expires 1h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~ ^/(libs|vendor|plugins|misc/user|node_modules) {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    ## properly display textfiles in root directory
    location ~/(.*\.md|LEGALNOTICE|LICENSE) {
        default_type text/plain;
    }
}
# vim: filetype=nginx
```

Comment: I doubt, it is possible to set `server_name` to anything else than a domain.
So you probably want to set up Matomo on a subdomain (or adapt your existing nginx config to also contain the Matomo related things)

Comment: thank you. That sounds about right... After further looking for solutions I now did actually both. I created a subdomain and was able to launch matomo under a subpage by adding the following code to the subdomain.config
   `location /matomo {
   root /var/www/subdomain.example.com/matomo;
    } `
thanks for helping me out !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply.

After further looking for solutions I have now done both: I created a subdomain and launched matomo under a subpage by adding the following code to the subdomain.config.

```
location /matomo {    
root /var/www/subdomain.example.com/matomo;
}
```

I found [this](https://hackprogramming.com/how-to-setup-subdomain-or-host-multiple-domains-using-nginx-in-linux-server/) to be a great tutorial on creating subdomains.

Comment: hi @hyde, will it be possible to share the nginx configuration files?